# using python opencv to calculate the volume of the box

Tags: python, opencv, volume

As shown in the figure, the blue board below the box is 60cm long and 45cm wide, and the pixel coordinates of the four corners of the blue board are obtained through corner detection. Is there a way to calculate the volume of the box above the board?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbCUD.jpg)

```
This is the code i'v try
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt\`

src = cv2.imread(r"D:\\project\\jetbot\\9.jpg")
print(type(src))
b, g, r = cv2.split(src)
dst = cv2.merge(\[b, g, r\])
cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
src = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(src)
Y, Cr, Cb = cv2.split(src)
dst = cv2.inRange(src, (70, 170, 145), (255, 255, 255))
src = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
dst.shape
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L09a.png)

```
edges = cv2.Canny(dst, 200,100)
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks(\[\]), plt.yticks(\[\])
plt.subplot(1,1,1),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks(\[\]), plt.yticks(\[\])
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQRuw.png)

```
img = cv.imread(r"D:\\project\\jetbot\\p4.png")
gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
\#corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,40,0.001,15)
corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,10,0.05,8)
corners = np.int0(corners)
x_id =\[\]
y_id =\[\]  
for i in corners:
x,y = i.ravel()
x_id.append(x)
y_id.append(y)
cv.circle(img,(x,y),2,255,-1)
plt.imshow(img),plt.show()\`
```